# How to shutdown os after running the function?

Tags: bash

Here is my bash function.

```
myfuns(){
    do something
}
```

I want to shutdown pc after running it.
It is my way for the target.
1.To inupt `myfuns` in terminal.
2.To wait myfuns until all job done,to input `shutdown -P` in terminal

I want to write it as a whole one command,how can?
limitation:keep myfuns unchanged.

Comment: Couldn't you just define another function myFuncAndShutdown that calls `myfuns; shutdown -P`?

Comment: And don't really understand your problem. You can first call your function and then run the shutdown command. myfuns and afterthat sudo shutdown -h now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rename your function and write another function:

```
myrealfuns(){
    do something
}

myfuns(){
    myrealfuns
    shutdown -P
}
```

Or you make an alias which will call your function, though this only works if you call it from an interactive shell afaik, the alias is not used if you call it from within the script.

```
alias myfuns="myfuns ; shutdown -P"
```

Comment: alias myfuns="myfuns ; shutdown -P"